# In Java 8, transform Optional<String> of an empty String in Optional.empty

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Given a String I need to get an Optional, whereby if the String is null or empty the result would be Optional.empty.
I can do it this way:

```
String ppo = "";
Optional<String> ostr = Optional.ofNullable(ppo);
if (ostr.isPresent() && ostr.get().isEmpty()) {
    ostr = Optional.empty();
}
```

But surely there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: If you can live with it returning an empty String instead of Optional.empty you could do this: Optional.ofNullable(ppo).orElse("");

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```
Optional.ofNullable(s).filter(not(String::isEmpty));
```

That will return an empty Optional if `ppo` is null or empty.

Answer (score 23):

With Apache Commons:

```
.filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
```

Comment: My case was that I couldn't take even for blanks, so used StringUtils.isNotBlank - however approach is same. thanks.

Comment: from java 11 you dont need apache commons anymore, just use `.filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))`

Answer (score 13):

Java 11 answer:

```
var optionalString = Optional.ofNullable(str).filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank));
```

`String::isBlank` deals with a broader range of 'empty' characters.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Optional<String> ostr = ppo == null || ppo.isEmpty()
    ? Optional.empty()
    : Optional.of(ppo);
```

You can put that in a utility method if you need it often, of course. I see no benefit in creating an `Optional` with an empty string, only to then ignore it.

Comment: @assylias: Fixed. It's never clear to me in Java how type inference works with the conditional operator. (Or rather, I never remember...)

Comment: With Java 8 it has become very rare that you need it.

Comment: from java 11 you can keep concatenating with filter and predicate, no other dependencies are needed: `Optional.ofNullable(s).filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))` as written in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212977/1636173

Answer (score 3):

If you use Guava, you can just do:

```
Optional<String> ostr = Optional.ofNullable(Strings.emptyToNull(ppo));
```

Comment: from java 11 you dont need guava anymore, just use `.filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use map :

```
String ppo="";
Optional<String> ostr = Optional.ofNullable(ppo)
                                .map(s -> s.isEmpty()?null:s);
System.out.println(ostr.isPresent()); // prints false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using filter

```
Optional<String> ostr = Optional.ofNullable(ppo).filter(o -> !o.isBlank());
```