# Java Optional Null Json Field

Tags: java, json, jackson, option-type, predicate

I am using the JsonNode objects from the Jackson library to hold json responses. I could potentially have a json like so:

```
{
    "a": "test",
    "b": true
}
```

However, at times the `b` field could be missing. So it could come back like this:

```
{
    "a": "test"
}
```

In that case I want to return `Optional.isEmpty()` when I'm trying to retrieve its value. Essentially this is the java code for that:

```
if(json.path("b").isMissingNode()) {
    return Optional.empty();
} else {
    return Optional.of(json.get("b").asBoolean());
}
```

However, I want to condense this into 1 line using `.filter` and `.ofNullable` but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322464/in-java-8-transform-optionalstring-of-an-empty-string-in-optional-empty) that shows an example of how to use the filter but I understand what the `s` is....

Basically I want to find the field labeled `b`, if it's not there then return empty. If it is there then return the boolean value of it's field.

Edit: This is not a duplicate because I am not serializing the entire json into an object. I don't have any need for the JsonIgnore annotations. I only want to extract 1 value. Which is like above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because I'm not serializing into an object. I'm just extracting 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like so:

```
Optional<Boolean> b = Optional.ofNullable(json.get("b"))
                              .map(node -> node.asBoolean());
```

A couple of points worth noting:

- You don't need to use `filter`. `ofNullable` is going to return an empty nullable. According to [Jackson documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(java.lang.String)), null is returned if node value is not present.
- Closely related to your question about `s` in referenced question, `map` is a function that is run only when the `Optional` is present (e.g. JSON has `b` value). It takes a lambda expression which is an equivalent of using an anonymous class. `node` is a parameter for the `Function` interface that has only one method (`apply`). You can take a look at the examples [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/lambda-expressions-in-java-8/240166764).